# reindex an array using value from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array structure returned from a db laravel select that looks like this:

```
array:219 [▼
  0 => {#236 ▼
    +"mID": "101"
    +"qAVG": "6.44444"
  }
  1 => {#235 ▼
    +"mID": "102"
    +"qAVG": "4.15068"
  }
```

Apart from looping through the entire array and creating a new variable, is there a function in PHP that can generate something like this:

```
Array = array(
  101 => array(
           'qAVG' => 6.44444
            ),

  101 => array(
           'qAVG' => 4.15068
            )
)
```

Comment: No, it is impossible to have duplicate keys on the same level of an array. (`101`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a function for that [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), which lets you extract a specific element from a multi-dimensional array and/or index the result by a specific element.  So do both:

```
$result = array_column($array, 'qAVG', 'mID');
```

If the sub-arrays have more elements and you want them as well, then just re-index:

```
$result = array_column($array, null, 'mID');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you hadn't converted to an array in Laravel you could use the collection function `pluck()`:

```
DB::table('foo')->select(['mID', 'qAVG'])->get()->pluck('qAVG', 'mID');
```

The first argument is what to pluck out, the second is what to use as the keys.  It's great for populating a select dropdown with options.

Similar to the above comment, if you need the other columns:

```
DB::table('foo')->get()->keyBy('mID');
```